# How could I update MongoDB array fileds based on array of another array fields

Tags: mongodb

**I have this document in my collection**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("609111c7ba749712215cff37"),
  "CompanyExperience" : {
    "Company1" : {
      "CompanyName" : "NWS Pvt. Ltd",
      "JobTitle" : "",
      "From" : "01/03/2017",
      "Till" : "30/11/2020",
      "ExperienceMonths" : NumberDecimal("9"),
      "ExperienceYears" : NumberDecimal("3")
    },
    "Company2" : {
      "CompanyName" : "KHS InfoTech Studio Pvt",
      "JobTitle" : "Sales-Coordinators",
      "From" : "01/08/2016",
      "Till" : "28/02/2017",
      "ExperienceMonths" : NumberDecimal("6"),
      "ExperienceYears" : NumberDecimal("0")
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to update CompanyExperience.Company1.JobTitle = CompanyExperience.Company2.JobTitle

**I have tried with this code**

```
db.mongodb_tbl_resumecard_all.updateOne(
    {"_id" : ObjectId("609111c7ba749712215cff37")},
    {$set:
        {
            "CompanyExperience.Company1.JobTitle": "$CompanyExperience.Company2.JobTitle"
        }
    }
)
```

But I got

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("609111c7ba749712215cff37"),
  "CompanyExperience" : {
    "Company1" : {
      "CompanyName" : "NWS Pvt. Ltd",
      "JobTitle" : "$CompanyExperience.Company2.JobTitle",
      "From" : "01/03/2017",
      "Till" : "30/11/2020",
      "ExperienceMonths" : NumberDecimal("9"),
      "ExperienceYears" : NumberDecimal("3")
    },
    "Company2" : {
      "CompanyName" : "KHS InfoTech Studio Pvt",
      "JobTitle" : "Sales-Coordinators",
      "From" : "01/08/2016",
      "Till" : "28/02/2017",
      "ExperienceMonths" : NumberDecimal("6"),
      "ExperienceYears" : NumberDecimal("0")
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to update its value but It is updating like string.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your $set operation in [] brackets to form an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.mongodb_tbl_resumecard_all.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("609111c7ba749712215cff37")
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "CompanyExperience.Company1.JobTitle": "$CompanyExperience.Company2.JobTitle"
    }
  }
])
```